# Extract a value from a ScheduledTask array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, extract

everyone. I am newbie to Powershell. So your help is much appreciated.

My question is the following. I have a powershell small script that provides me with server Start, Stop, Kill ... tasks.

Here's the command

```
PS P:\> Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "*$someString*" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select TaskName,LastRunTime,NextRunTime

TaskName       LastRunTime                             NextRunTime
--------       -----------                             -----------
Archive        10/14/2017 7:00:00 AM                   10/21/2017 7:00:00 AM
Kill           10/15/2017 12:50:50 PM                  10/22/2017 12:50:50 PM
Restart        10/20/2017 12:00:00 AM                  10/23/2017 12:00:00 AM
Start          10/15/2017 1:00:00 PM                   10/22/2017 1:00:00 PM
Stop           10/13/2017 5:30:30 PM                   10/20/2017 5:30:30 PM
```

I would like to extract the value of LastRunTime that corresponds to Start and the value of NextRunTime that corresponds to stop, and have them converted to a String.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very useful in the requested OP format, but here you go

```
C:\> $TaskNames = "Start","Stop"
C:\> $data = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskNames | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
C:\> [string]"$(($data | sort)[0].LastRunTime) $(($data | sort)[1].NextRunTime)"
10/20/2017 08:15:15 10/21/2017 09:16:16
```

this will only work right if your task names are actually in alphabetical order. Change the indexes (numbers in `[]`) if the sort comes out in a different order.